# Plotting graphs with error ribbons in python

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, scipy

for a while I've been trying to come up with a good way to graphically represent a data series along with its estimated error.

Recently I saw some graphs where the data was plotted as a line, with a background 'ribbon' filling the area between the lines plotting data +/- sigma.

Is there a name for this type of graph, and is there any python toolkit which has the capability to make such plots?

A simple way to fake it with matplotlib would also be useful - right now I'm just plotting three lines, but I don't know how to fill the area between them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use the `fill_between` [method](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between). Look at the [Our Favorite Recipes](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/recipes.html#fill-between-and-alpha) section of the manual for matplotlib for some good examples. They have one that looks like this:

[image]

and another that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Providing a code example would make this a complete answer :).  Its generally frowned upon to just drop links as answers.  This currently reads more like a comment.